# Can I password protect/childproof iPad apps?

Tags: software-recommendation, ipad

I have ordered an iPad 2. I was wondering if I could protect applications that I don't want my 7-year old to muck about in.

It's stuff like Mail, Things, Evernote, and perhaps some games not suited for a small child.

I'm OK with paying for it if there are good third party solutions but it should be able to protect any app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't generally password protect specific apps without some jailbreaking I assume, but you can restrict certain things, a few of which I recommend if you are giving it to a young one.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213 Describes the restrictions process, and it lists

> You can choose to restrict access to the following applications and features on the device:
>
> Safari,
> YouTube,
> iTunes,
> Ping,
> App installation,
> App deletion,
> Camera,
> FaceTime,
> Location,
> Account changes,
> Multiplayer games in Game Center,
> Adding friends in Game Center.
>
> In addition, you can choose to prevent access to specific content types:
> In-app purchases,
> Music and podcasts,
> Movies,
> TV shows,
> Apps.

You can also set iTunes restrictions for content via http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1904, but again, this isn't device specific at the time, it is when you are buying or downloading content from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any kind of app that does that, because it would interfere with Apples Terms.

You can't even lock the iPad to a specific app once it's opened.. The best thing you can do is get your hands on a casing without a hole for the home button, so your child can't get out of the app you let him/her in to.

Comment: This is incorrect - in Settings, under General -> Accessibility -> Guided Access you can set up a passcode that will lock user to one app and won't let them use the Home button unless they provide a passcode.

Comment: Wow, and only 6 years later ;)

Comment: Matias Vad I know right! Still no way to passcode lock an individual app. I guess we don't really need it???

Answer (score 0):

On a jailbroken iPad on iOS 5, Applocker can lock any app so that it requires a password to open it - [one review of Applocker](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/10/24/applocker/) and [another](http://modmyi.com/content/6474-review-applocker-2-going-live-cydia-tonight.html). It costs $1 via the Cydia Store.

If you want to lock a specific app open (so that kids can play with it but can't close it), IncarcerApp is a free tweak also for jailbroken iOS devices - [a review of it](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2010/11/12/incarcerapp/), and [a list of features](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=incarcerappData).